# How can I get "pip show" to show the date and time when module was installed?

Tags: linux, shell-script, python, pip

how to know when module for example requests was installed - in date and  hour and min

for example pip show show only the following details without time

```
pip show  requests
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: requests
Version: 2.6.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to know when module for example requests was installed - in date and hour and min

[`pip-date`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-date/) can be used to get the installation times.

> ```
> Show the installation/modification times of all your pip packages and other tools
> ```

`pip-date` [on github](https://github.com/E3V3A/pip-date).